# Linux and C/C++ :Appliction created by linking libc-2.11 and trying to run on Linux machine which has libc-2.5.so

Tags: c++, c, linux

I get the folloing error when trying to run.

lib/libc.so.6: version "GLIBC_2.7" not found required by (test.so)

To fix this problem , is it safe to do static linking to libc-2.11.a at compilation so that there won't be any dependency on libc.so at runtime.

Any comments are appreciated.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever installed the GLIBC, if so, make sure the version is 2.7, and try again.